# Why does Magento 2 combine orders

Tags: magento2, orders, combine

We have noticed that our Magento 2 install combines orders from customers.

This is something we don't want, is this a setting or is this something we can change very easily

Comment: have you use any extension/module for that ? if yes then disabled it

Comment: No, we didn't in stall something extra that would control this function, I was hoping that this was a Magento 2 functionality that could be easily disabled

Comment: Combine in what way?

Comment: If someone orders something and very quickly orders something else, it would be combined in one order.